# How to upload (client-side) & read CSV "abstract" data on D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filereader

I'm actually stuck on my researches. I'd like to create some graphs using D3 (like bar-chart) from CSV files just by uploading them.

I've found something very interesting (http://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459), but, it's using JSON, and each information in the file is clearly identified by a name (nodes, edges).

I did something like that :

```
    d3.select("#upload-input").on("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("hidden-file-upload").click();
});
d3.select("#hidden-file-upload").on("change", function(){
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        //Files vars
        var uploadFile = this.files[0];
        var filereader = new window.FileReader();

        filereader.onload = function(){
            //Txt file output
            var txtRes = filereader.result;
            try{
                //TODO Read CSV
                var data = d3.csv.parse(txtRes);
```

But i'm now stuck with this method (*d3.csv.parse()*).

Imagine a CSV like this :

```
   chr19_pos17941294_SNV_C_JAK3;chr2_pos216242917_SNV_A_FN1;chr21_pos46320313_SNV_T_ITGB2;chr5_pos138266546_SNV_A_CTNNA1;chr6_pos160468278_SNV_G_IGF2R
   15;11;21;11;41;31
```

(It's DNA genes & how many patients do have them).

So, first, how to use the parsing method ? And, secondly, how to catch each column name correctly ?

I thought something like that would work to access the names:

```
data[0]
```

But, I made some tests, it's not I just get JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not loading a CSV (C=comma) but an "SSV" (S=semi-colon). `d3.csv.parse` assumes it's getting an actual csv, so you can't use it. However, d3 has a lower level object — which `d3.csv` uses behind the scenes — that can parse any DSV (D=delimeter). It's called `d3.dsv`, and it's documented [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#dsv). So your code can do something like

```
    filereader.onload = function(){
        //Txt file output
        var txtRes = filereader.result;
        // Init the "SSV" parser, which splits data on semi-colons
        var parser = d3.dsv(';')
        try{
            // Parse the data
            var data = parser.parse(txtRes);
```

Based on your example data, the parsed `data` will be:

```
[
    {
        "chr19_pos17941294_SNV_C_JAK3": "15",
        "chr2_pos216242917_SNV_A_FN1": "11",
        "chr21_pos46320313_SNV_T_ITGB2": "21",
        "chr5_pos138266546_SNV_A_CTNNA1": "11",
        "chr6_pos160468278_SNV_G_IGF2R": "41"
    }
]
```